# why asp-route-ID not working in this code?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4, routes, tag-helpers

```
 <a asp-page="\Products\Details" asp-route-ID="@products.Product_ID"                   
               class="btn btn-primary m-1">View</a>
```

route ID not working here in this code .Please suggest.
This also doesn't working for asp-route- tag

View

Comment: <a asp-page="\Products\Details" asp-route-ID="@products.Product_ID"                   
                   class="btn btn-primary m-1">View</a>


route ID not working here in this code .Please suggest.
This also doesn't working for asp-route- tag 

   <a asp-page="\Products\Details" asp-route-Product_ID="@products.Product_ID"                   
                   class="btn btn-primary m-1">View</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 <a asp-page="../Products/Details" asp-route-ID="@products.Product_ID"                   
           class="btn btn-primary m-1">View</a>
```

In your `/Products/Details` get action:

```
public IActionResult OnGet(int ID)
    {
        return Page();
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to mark it useful but its not allowing me as I am a new user. It says you need 15 reputation to cast vote.. So I am unable to mark it as useful answers.

Comment: Now I could do a tick mark, but  still unable to upvote.. However , I tick marked.